# mutiple time data saving problem in django sqllite3

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i using django with sqllite i create a survey form with the help of django model and django forms but when i hit submit i see sometime data save twice in my database is it happen normally or something wrong with my code

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from .forms import SurveyForm


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SurveyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return TemplateResponse(request, 'thankyou.html')
        else:
            return messages.error(request, 'Please fill the form to continue')
    else:
        form = SurveyForm()
        return render(request, 'learnersform.html', {'form': form})
```

my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from .models import teacher

class teachersform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = teacher
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Your Name'}),
                    'Q3': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Please write your subjects'}),
                    'Q4': forms.RadioSelect(),
                    'Q5': forms.RadioSelect(),
                    'Q6': forms.RadioSelect(),
                    'Q7': forms.RadioSelect(),
                    'Q8': forms.RadioSelect(),
                    'Q9':forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Write Here.......'}),
                    'Q10':forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Write Here.......'}),
                   }
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True,)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=state_choice,)
    Q3 = models.CharField(max_length=80, default=None, blank=False)
    Q4 = models.CharField(max_length=80, choices=q4_choice, default=None, blank=False)
    Q5 = models.CharField(max_length=80, choices=q5_choice, default=None, blank=False)
    Q6 = models.CharField(max_length=80, choices=q6_choice, default=None, blank=False)
    Q7 = models.CharField(max_length=80, choices=q7_choice, default=None, blank=False)
    Q8 = models.CharField(max_length=80, choices=q8_choice, default=None, blank=False)
    Q9 = models.TextField(default=None, blank=False)
    Q10 = models.TextField(default=None,blank=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.state
```

Comment: Your view seems fine, Can you add your `SurveyForm` class as well as the corresponding model?

Comment: Please show the relevant form and models

Comment: added the form and model

Comment: You haven't added the correct form or model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issues is not related with sqlite but rather with the code in views.py. When you refresh your page after the form has been saved, the same form data getting resubmitted; and same data is getting saved multiple times.

It is recommended that after the form data is successfully saved, a return [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) or [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) should be used rather than rendering using the [HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects).

I would rewrite the code as

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SurveyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('thankyou/')
            #return TemplateResponse(request, 'thankyou.html')
        else:
            return messages.error(request, 'Please fill the form to continue')
    else:
        form = SurveyForm()
        return render(request, 'learnersform.html', {'form': form})
```

Add a route to the urls.py like

```
path( 'thankyou/', views.thankyou, name='thankyou')
```

Include another function *thankyou* in views.py

```
def thankyou(request):
  return render(request, 'thankyou.html')
```

**Update:**

In case you don't want to use the urls.py route and the extra view function, then you can pass the path *thankyou.html* to the HttpResponseRedirect constructor. In this case, no need to create route in urls.py or the extra view function.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('thankyou.html')
```

Comment: but what it create a extra link in website but i dont want that thankyou.html page have it's own path

Comment: Sure. The first argument to the HttpResponseRedirect constructor can be either an URL, relative path or absolute path.

You can simply replace the HttpResponseRedirect statement with return HttpResponseRedirect('thankyou.html')

In this case, you neither need the url route nor the view function.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally suggest you extract the data from the form before saving, you can then manipulate the data, or save in other locations as well:

Firstly you will know how the data will be sent through by the names given in the form, so you can build out a dictionary of values...

You will need to build out the 'form_data' section to get a complete dict that is relevant to your form.

```
form_data = {
            "name": request.POST['name'],
            "Q3": request.POST['Q3']
my_form = SurveyForm(form_data)

if my_form.is_valid():
    new_form = my_form.save(commit=False)
    """
    Now you can access any data using the dict method - new_form.name, new_form.Q3 
    etc. Even if you don't initially use it, you can leave this section blank but use 
    it in the future at some stage...
    new_form.name for example will be the users name entered on the form.
    new_form.Q3 will be the answer to question 3. 
    Although this may be a longer way of doing things, it will allow you to gather the 
    form data, before saving it. You can also build in additional security features 
    prior to database submission.
    """

    if new_form.Q3 == "Some Specific Answer":
         # Add all users to list who answer Q3 in a certain way
         some_list.extend(new_form.name)  

    # Now your done manipulating data, or pushing it to be saved in other places, you can save the form to your database.
    new_form.save()
else:
    # Form was not valid
    messages.error(request, 'Please fill the form to continue')
```

Not sure what the scope of your project is but the above way will allow you to easily grow its code into the future as you can manipulate that data, for example you could push users names into different collections based on question results etc.